# Existing external timber columns paint peeling off after 9 months - how to fix?

Tags: wood, paint, carpentry

I've got some existing external timber columns.
The columns are 30+ years old.

They are not solid wood, but rather boards, used to make the uprights and then timber mouldings to make the "feet".

The column was painted about 9 months ago and the paint is already flaking off.

Is there anything that can be done to the columns design eg. making sure the moulding dosnt touch the ground, or to the paint / prep that will make this stop ?

I don't want to paint it again only to have the same issue in a few months time.

[image: image of timber column with flaking paint]

Comment: What is inside of those columns?  It looks like sign of bad prep or moisture when painted.

Comment: The paint has flaked off recently and it looks like its a piece of plywood or timber board, and of resin epoxy wood repair

Comment: I am asking if those columns are covering up/hiding something like pipes, pipes that might have a leak, or if a leak could be coming down from the top, like a roof leak.

Comment: Fix the leak (whatever the source) or paint will just peel off again.

Comment: sorry i should state these columns are outside, the source of the. water is the weather

Comment: Paint should last longer than 9 months to the rain hitting it.  Quite possible rain/water is getting inside the columns, though a crack, a seam/seal opening up.

Comment: As well as fixing the source of the water, there are paints designed to allow water through in one direction.

Comment: Could be there's just poor adhesion at the bottom, allowing water to wick up beneath the paint.